# how i can disable php 8 and enable php7.4 in arch linux

Tags: php, archlinux

when I run the command `php -v`
I have version 8.0
I would like to change the version to 7.4
despite I have installed php7.4
but I don't know how to switch between the two versions

thank you

Comment: For nginx, you can use php-fpm socket with your version like ´fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;´

Comment: @JackSparrow this seems to be a CLI-based question, as the asker runs a CLI command to find out the version rather than looking at the settings of the webserver.

Comment: @LajosArpad that is why i wrote that as a comment.

Comment: just add a [ref](https://serverfault.com/questions/1052022/how-to-properly-set-specific-php-version-used-by-apache-on-arch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that the location of php7.4 is **/usr/bin/php7.4**, in which case

```
/usr/bin/php7.4 -v
```

will yield something like this:

[image]

hence, you can use this method for whatever command that you would like to execute:

```
/usr/bin/php7.4 <yourcommand>
```

You can disable PHP 8 via

```
sudo a2dismod php8.0
```

if it bothers you. You can do so temporarily as well.

Comment: yes this solution work in ubuntu but not in arch linux

Comment: The question was how to do this in arch, you provided an answer that only works in ubuntu. Does not actually resolve the question as asked. Downvoted.

Comment: @mopsyd thanks for the reason given for the down-vote. I do not have Archlinux to test this, but the fact that this answer was accepted suggests that it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is about the **Arch Linux** and it doesn't have the `a2enmod` & `a2dismod`. I am gonna providing working answer in the arch:

I assume you have installed php7 & php8 and just want to make apache to use the version 7.

first uninstall apache-php module and install the right one.

```
sudo pacman -R php-apache  
sudo pacman -S php7-apache
```

then in the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` change the module name:

from :

```
LoadModule php_module modules/libphp.so
Include conf/extra/php_module.conf
AddHandler php-script php
```

to:

```
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
Include conf/extra/php7_module.conf
AddHandler php7-script php
```

after that you can reload the server:

```
sudo systemctl reload httpd
```